# Encapsulate enum

Tags: c#, visual-studio, enumeration

I´m trying to understand how to use enumerations in c#. I already googled it but I can´t figure out how to encapsulate an enumeration.

I have a class which contains an enum attribute. How do I encapsulate this attribute so I can use it outside the class?

```
private enum cost { Price, Diff };
```

Comment: Eh, make it *public*? `public enum Cost { Price, Diff };`... `public Cost MyCost {get; set;}` for a property

Comment: Isn´t necessary to declare get and set?

Comment: @Gunoi An `enum` is just another type definition, but constrained to certain value types for a targeted use case. You seem to be confused between declaring an `enum` as above, and applying that `enum` as a property, field, or parameter.

Comment: Think of an `enum` as a bunch of grouped constants and that will probably help you conceptualise it. However, this could easily have been answered by trying to learn yourself what an enum actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to *declare* the enum:

```
  public enum Cost { 
    Price, 
    Diff 
  };
```

then use it

```
  public class MyClass {
    // property of "Cost" type
    public Cost MyCost {
      get;
      set; 
    }
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move the enum declaration outside of the class as below, then this can be used from all over the project as `cost cos = cost.Price`

```
public enum cost 
    {
        Price, Diff
    }

    public class ExampleClass
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just treat the enum as a normal class object.

So lets say you have this enum:

```
public enum CoffeType
{
    regular,
    decaf
}
```

and you have a class:

```
public class CoffeeOrder
{
    public string CustomerName {get;set}
    public CoffeeType CoffeeType {get;set;}
    // ..other properties 
}
```

and you see that the enum is encapsulated just like a normal class property...